# Filter rows by conditions on one particular column

Tags: r, filter, subset

How could I subset rows by any condition I want based on a single column?

Original data:

```
  name num
1    A   1
2    B  -1
3    C   5
4    D   0
5    E   1
```

Subset all rows where num > 0

```
  name num
1    A   1
3    C   5
5    E   1
```

Subset all rows where num < 0

```
  name num
2    B  -1
```

Subset all rows where num < & = 0

```
  name num
2    B  -1
4    D   0
```

Comment: Use `subset` i.e. `subset(df1, num < 0)` and similarly create the other conditions and the last would be `num<= 0`

Comment: Not working at the moment. Can "num" be an integer?

Comment: I assumed the class as numeric/integer. Check the `str(df1)`

Comment: Right, ok, so that's not the problem. My new df: x<- subset(dat, num < 0) is all the variables of my original df, but no data.

Comment: Looks good for cols with character strings, how does it work for numbers?

Comment: Wait, got it. df[df$num >0, ]. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @akrun's first comment should have worked. Once again, check `str(df1)`.